# Alert DialogBox not showing in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am  having the main activity and a simple class.The main activity is having the dialog box method and i am calling this method from another class

Main activity-

```
public class WishareActivity extends Activity

 {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.main);

   activity=this;

  //handler to call alertmsg()method

    alerthandler= new Handler() {
        public  void handleMessage(Message msg){

            alertmsg();
        } 
    }; 

      layouthandler= new Handler() {
        public  void handleMessage(Message msg){

            setContentView(R.layout .main);
        } 
    }; 


}


    //method to show the dialog box

   public static  void alertmsg()
{
     AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(WishareActivity.activity);

    alert.setTitle("Confirm");
    alert.setMessage("abc");

    alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {




            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Log.d("abc","alert alert");
    AlertDialog s=alert.create();
    s.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() { 
        public void onDismiss( DialogInterface dialog) { 

        }
    });

     Log.d("abc1","alert alert");

  alert.show();
 Log.d("abc1","alert alert alert");
    return;

}
```

connect.class

```
public class connect implements Runnable
{

 public void run()
    {

         WishareActivity.layouthandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
         WishareActivity.alerthandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}
```

In the Logcat its showing

```
  abc : alert alert
  abc1: alert alert
  abc1 :alert alert alert
```

According to the log the method is called correctly but the dialog box is not showing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: have you tried this AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(WishareActivity.this);

Comment: yes I tried .When  I called this method from the main activity then the dialog box is showing properly

Comment: if you have any error in that code

Comment: why are you again setting layout for the same activity? may be that is causing problem

Comment: @tamil..its giving error regarding static context is not allowed

Comment: @abhinav I tried but not worked

Answer (score 0):

change your alert dialog method

```
public static  void alertmsg()
```

to this

```
public static  void alertmsg(Context context)
```

use this context variable like this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

and when using this method do like this

```
WishareActivity.alertmsg(someactivity.this); // here someactivity will be the activity name where you are calling alert method
```

your dialog will work very fine.

Comment: I am calling this method from the class and not the activity.Also from thread , so the use of handler is must

Comment: on just incase option call this alertdialog method into runOnUiThread() and check if it still not working and do not set the layout for the activity again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

you create the method without static like this

```
public void alertmsg();
```

Because the class is not support the static. It displays this error below

```
   Cannot use this in a static context
```

I am sure this will be works

Comment: The same code working for me after remove the static.So please clean and run the project once..

Comment: replace this into method AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(WishareActivity.this);